# if the dictionary type is [String: Any], am I able to get to value of a specific value?

Tags: swift

```
let josmith = [["Name": "Joe Smith"], ["Height": 42], ["SE": "YES"], ["Guardian Name(s)": "Jim and Jan Smith"]]
```

How can I get the Int value of 42?

Comment: You have `[[String, Any]]` (array of dictionary). There doesn't seem to be any reason for the array.

Comment: That's an array of dictionary (with only one key/value each). How do you look for 42? Because you know it's for the key "Height"?

Comment: @Larme Is there a way to get the value 42? or how can I fix this to get the value 42?

Comment: @rmaddy How can I fix this to get the value of 42?

Comment: Make it a simple dictionary (get rid of the array) and then simply access the desired value by the key `"Height"`.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? This structure makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

You've made an array of dictionaries, eg [[String:Any]].
You said you wanted a dictionary, [String:Any], so construct it like this instead (note that it's not required to put elements on new lines, it just aids readability):

```
let josmith = ["Name": "Joe Smith",
               "Height": 42, 
               "SE": "YES", 
               "Guardian Name(s)": "Jim and Jan Smith"]
```

Then access it like this:

```
if let fortyTwo = josmith["Height"] as? Int {
   // fortyTwo == 42
} else {
   // josmith did not contain "Height" or it wasn't an Int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I assume dictionary in array will always have only one value.

```
    let josmith = [["Name": "Joe Smith"], ["Height": 42], ["SE": "YES"], ["Guardian Name(s)": "Jim and Jan Smith"]]
    for pairs in josmith {
        guard pairs.keys.first == "Height" else {
            continue
        }
        guard let integerValue = pairs.first?.value as? Int else {
            continue
        }
        print("Your value is \(integerValue)")
    }
```

Will result:

> Your value is 42

Comment: But there could be other `Int` values besides the height.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I added simple improvement. For me more improvements would require json scheme or at least more examples to work on.